# Down-converting dictionary comprehensions to generator expressions for Python 2.6 compliance

Tags: python, dictionary, python-2.6

I have Python 2.7 code filled with dictionary comprehensions `{x(i):y(i) for i in ...}`. I have access to a compute cluster on which I can only run Python 2.6.6. The dictionary comprehensions are not part of the time-consuming part of the code, so I'm not very worried about speed.

I'm looking for the easiest way to make my code Python 2.6.6 and Python 2.7.6 compliant, preferably actually using the dictionary comprehensions where that is supported. Manually changing each expression to `dict((x(i),y(i)) for i in ...)` isn't preferred.

Comment: You cannot use syntax that won't work on older python versions, not without rewriting your code on install.

Comment: For what it's worth, can't you ask them to have your python installed? Sometimes you just have to ask or find the right person... Downgrading code is senseless.

Comment: is there any advantage to sticking with the new-style comprehensions, other than aesthetics?

Comment: @CorleyBrigman: Readability is a pretty big advantage…

Comment: Is your question whether it's possible to write a source-code-processor (which you could run before building your distributable package, or make it run as part of install, or even postpone until runtime as an import hook) that will convert dict comprehensions to Python 2.6-compatible syntax? Or something different?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I think he already knows everything in that question and answer, and is looking for an alternative to manually converting all of his dict comps to the `dict(genexpr)` format, which he knows how to do but doesn't want to.

Comment: @abarnert: exactly; but that wasn't the question here, not yet. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Sure, but now that it is in the question, people should not follow your code-as-dup vote.

Comment: @abarnert: fair enough, retracted my vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always write a source-processor that converts your 2.7 code to 2.6 code.

Or, just use one that someone else wrote. The [`3to2`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/3to2) project has, among its fixers, one named `dctsetcomp`.* And it looks like it does exactly what you want. Here's a sample of its output:

```
RefactoringTool: Refactored dc.py
--- dc.py   (original)
+++ dc.py   (refactored)
@@ -1 +1 @@
-{x(i):y(i) for i in z}
+dict((x(i), y(i)) for i in z)
RefactoringTool: Files that need to be modified:
RefactoringTool: dc.py
```

There's not much documentation on how to use it, but basically it's meant to work exactly like [`2to3`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html), which is documented nicely, and used in hundreds of projects on PyPI if you need examples.

You can manually run this on your code before you're ready to distribute it, or run it as a pre-build step in `setup.py` (either unconditionally, or only if running on 2.6). `setuptools` makes it trivial to add a `2to3` step to the build/install process; subverting that to run `3to2` instead should be easy, but I haven't actually tried it.

---

You might want to look at the source to `3to2`, or the stdlib's [`2to3`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/default/Lib/lib2to3), if you want to write your own fixers, or if you need to debug/improve this one, or want to write a simpler parser from scratch.

---

A third place you can run a fixer is at *runtime*, with an import hook. Look at [`MacroPy`](https://github.com/lihaoyi/macropy) as a great example of an import hook.

MacroPy is also a great example of code that works on ASTs instead of raw source. If you wanted to build a distribution-time fixer, this might be handy, because then you could let Python 2.7 parse the Python 2.7 source so you don't have to.

---

If `3to2` doesn't work out, you can probably do something a lot simpler, by limiting what you write in your code to what your parser can handle. For example, you could set yourself the rule that a dict comprehension must be the only dict display on the line, and be followed by `#dc`. Then you just have to search for lines ending with `#dc`, find the braces, and parse the result—which means you only have to parse a small subset of Python that's a regular language, which means you can do it with simple regexps.

---

* Why would a tool designed to port 3.2+ code to 2.7 have a dict comprehension fixer? Because it was originally designed to port 3.1+ code to 2.6, and the author never removed the no-longer-needed fixers. So, you got lucky. :)